# Using FacePlusPlus API with OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

[FacePlusPlus](http://www.faceplusplus.com/) provides a number of features in detecting some facial features of a person and previously I have been using FacePlusPlus before and the results returned are very useful to me.

I want to use the FacePlusPlus API in part of my OpenCV project for facial features extraction but somehow I couldn't figure out how. The documentation does not provide a guide for using the FacePlusPlus API with my C++ codes.

Is there any way that I could use the FacePlusPlus API with my OpenCV project (related to SVM regression)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found this on Github

https://github.com/xiangzhai/faceplusplus

which is somewhat similar on what I were looking for.